# I install the Google Plugin 4.4 in my eclipse LUNA (version 4.40) , but I don't know it and which GWT Designer plug-in matching

Tags: gwt, google-plugin-eclipse, gwt-designer

I choosed this version of google Plugin: https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4
but I should choose which version of  GWT Designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT Designer isn't maintained and won't work with latest version of GWT. You'd better not spend time trying to install/configure it.